# How can I join data from different tables?

Tags: sql, vba, oracle

[image]

**The Problem**

I use VBA and I would like to import all the data that is available for specific `employeeID` from an Oracle database. Unfortunately, the needed data is contained in four different tables. Taking the [w3schools-editor](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc)  as an example, I am interested into the tables Shippers, Orders, Customers and Products:

```
Name: Shippers 
_____________
ShipperID | ShipperName | ...
_____________
```

```
Name: Orders
_____________
OrderID | EmployeeID |ShipperID ...
...
_____________
```

```
Name: OrderDetails
_____________
OrderID | ProductID | ...
...
_____________
```

```
Name: Products
_____________
ProductID | ProductName | ...
...
_____________
```

For a specific `EmployeeID` in `Orders`, I wish to obtain a table of the form:

```
Name: Goal
_____________
ShipperName | ProductID | ProductName 
...
_____________
```

**What I tried so far:**

```
Select Shippers.ShipperName, Orders.OrderID, OrderDetails.ProductID 
From Orders
Inner Join OrderDetails On OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
Inner Join Shippers On Shippers.ShipperID = Orders.ShipperID
```

```
Select Distinct Orders.OrderID, OrderDetails.ProductID 
From OrderDetails
Inner Join Orders On
Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID And Orders.EmployeeID = 5
```

But in both cases I get errors.

I also tried to use `union`

```
Select ShipperName From Shippers
    Inner Join Orders On Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID
Union
Select ProductID From OrderDetails
    Inner Join Orders On Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
```

but then I get a table with one column containg the entries from the origial two columns.

I did not manage to get any further towards `Goal`

Any suggestions?

PS: I hope that it is clearer now.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and your actual working and not-working code; you have illegal and inconsistent names in the code you have posted so we can't even know if this is close to what you are actually running.

Comment: SQL `UNION` instead of `JOINS` should do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's see if this sql statement helps you:

```
SELECT Shippers.ShipperName, 
       Products.ProductID, 
       Products.ProductName
FROM Shippers
INNER JOIN Orders ON Shippers.ShipperID = Orders.ShipperID
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
```

so you can add the where condition:

```
WHERE Orders.employeeID = ?
```

Comment: Thanks this helped! I am still not sure why my original statement didn't work. But one Day I may understand.